# Getting weird FBSDKLog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7, xcode5

I've created App from https://developers.facebook.com/apps, **I'm getting weird error like > FBSDKLog: FBSession: a permission request for publish or manage permissions contains unexpected read permissions**
1. My Xcode Bundle ID matches with current Fb App 2. I'm using my App to publish Check Ins to my Friends
 I've given permissions to Publish Check Ins are as below code

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"public_profile",
                            @"basic_info",
                            @"user_friends",
                            @"status_update",
                            @"publish_actions",
                            @"publish_checkins",
                            @"user_checkins",
                            nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error)
```

Any Help will be appreciated -I'll provide more information if it's needed Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to separate your request for read permissions from write permissions and request them from the user in that order.

To request read permissions:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_checkin"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
```

To request write permissions:

```
[[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                        defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {

}];
```

You can read more about the new process in [Facebook iOS SDK Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading/); specifically, read the section, **Asking for Read & Write Permissions Separately**.